# How to access canvas control (wpf) in WinForm application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, canvas, user-controls

In my Windows Forms app I want to use a canvas control from WPF. I created an element host which contains the canvas .

```
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        canvas.AllowDrop = true;
    }
```

How can I access the canvas in my WinForm code?

Comment: Add a property to UserControl1: `public Canvas Canvas { get => canvas; }`

Comment: Thank You.I applied your advice.I wrote this piece of code as well:                                                           
           `//Add button to the canvas
            Button newButton = new Button();
           userControl11.canvas.Children.Add(newButton);`                                  But I'm getting an error(squirly line under _newButton_ ) stating: `Argument 1: Cannot convert System.Windows.Forms.Button to System.Windows.UIElement `.Basically what I want to achieve is in my WinForms app I want to allow user to add new button to the canvas.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `System.Windows.Forms.Button` is not a WPF Button. Use `System.Windows.Controls.Button` instead.